# JTable column name is be fold when adding column dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

I add column dynamically by this code:

```
myTableModel.addColumn(");
```

The problem is shown in the picture, have you noticed the four column and after column head is not show completely? I add column by table model dynamically, but the column width is not enough, I adjust width by `setPreferredWidth()`,but it is work for last column, when a new column is added, the previous column is not shown completely.

thansk your reply.
i decided edit problem again.i write a code to describe the problem.the code is following:

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        //i find the cause is UIManager setting
        //if(System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))
           //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"test"});
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            model.addColumn("column......." + i);
            //table.getColumn("column......." + i).setPreferredWidth(200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image could be described as 'a JTable' and that would describe everything that can be determined from it, so I won't edit it into the question. More words are needed, as the scant description above has me completely not understanding what you are trying to achieve or what problems you are experiencing. I especially don't understand *"be fold"*. Can you expand on that?

Comment: thanks your reply,actually i am a freshman for stackoverflow,and my native language is chinese.l know my description is poor and not clearly,probablelly because i am not sure i will get answer.and my expression ability is bad.the problem is show in the picture,have you noticed the four cloumn and after cloumn head is not show completely,i add column by table model dynamically,but the column width is not enough,i adjust width by setPreferredWidth(),but it is work for last column,when a new column is added,the previous column is still show uncompletely.i dont know whether i express clearly.

Comment: *"my native language is chinese"* Congrats on being multi-lingual, and thanks for taking the effort to express the problem in the only language I know (also the only language this section of SO should be conducted in). But the fact that you are translating into English is beside the point. You obviously understand enough English to be able to describe the problem to a technical forum, it's just a matter of taking the time to put the words. BTW - I edited the problem description into the question where it should be.

Comment: As an aside, 'code speaks all languages' and may be easier for people whose first language (mother tongue) is not English.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.

Comment: The default width of a TableColumn is 75 pixels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Column Widths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width) to manually control each column width.  Or you can check out the [Table Column Adjust](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) to automatically determine each column width.

Comment: i am appreciate your reply,i edit the question again.and i found the cause is UIManager setting.